# Why do I have so many CLASS files in bin folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, bin

I have a Java project operated in Eclipse with the main executable file called `GreatPlaces.java`. In my `/bin` folder, I would assume to have just one CLASS file called `GreatPlaces.class`. However, I have couple of them, except for `GreatPlaces.class` I have also `GreatPlaces$1.class`, `GreatPlaces$2.class` ... `GreatPlaces$22.class`. Can anyone explain me this? Thanks.

Comment: You probably are using [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in your code.

Comment: how can I find it out? And moreover, is it somehow harmful for the final release of the project?

Comment: Take a look at link in my comment. Normally anonymous classes are created by using `new SomeClassOrInterface(){additional implementation for SomeClassOrInterface};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inner classes if any present in your class will be compiled and the class file will be `ClassName$InnerClassName`. In the case of Anonymous inner classes, it will appear as numbers.

**Example:**

```
public class TestInnerOuterClass {
    class TestInnerChild{
        
    }
    
    Serializable annoymousTest = new Serializable() {
    };
}
```

For the above code, the classes that will be generated are:

1. `TestInnerOuterClass.class`
2. `TestInnerOuterClass$TestInnerChild.class`
3. `TestInnerOuterCasss$1.class`

Answer (score 4):

The dollar sign is used by the compiler for inner classes.

`$` sign represents inner classes. If it has a `number` after `$` then it is an annonymous inner class. If it has a `name` after `$` then it is only an inner class.

So in your casese these are representing annonymouse inner classes

Answer (score 2):

These class files correspond to anonymous inner classes that you use in the program.

Here's an example of an event handler that will be compiled into .class file of its own:

```
button.addActionLister(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { .... }
});
```